# How to show xml shape in background at specific place android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable

I have XML of the light brown circle and I want to place it as background on the top left corner as shown in the pic

[image]

Can anyone guide me on how I can do it? I need to show it on multiple screens on different sides. Any hint will be much appreciated

here is the XML of `circle`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/light_brown"/>
            <!-- Set the same value for both width and height to get a circular shape -->
            <size android:width="550sp" android:height="550sp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: If you already have xml ready just add it to a view's background . Whats the problem in this ?

Comment: @ADM I have xml of full circle but i am supposed to show half of the circle on top left corner as shown in the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `ImageView` in `ConstraintLayout` and add constraints of:

- `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"`: Making width and height equal (or as proportional as you want)
- `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"`: a percentage you need of the Width relative to the parent `ConstraintLayout`, here I see it half

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/quarter"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can use the following quarter of a circle drawable instead of a full circle

drawable\quarter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="15dp"
                android:height="15dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/light_brown" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="250dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: its showing full circle on the top left corner. And in the design tab its shows error on `layout_constraintDimensionRatio` saying that invalid float

Comment: @ZohabAli thanks for your comment ... for the invalid float, use `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"` instead check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208447/invalid-float-for-layout-constraintdimensionratio)

Comment: For the circle ... It depends on your drawable ... do you have a circle or a quarter of it ? can you share it

Comment: I have updated my question, you can check XML that I am using for circle

Comment: thanks, it works in this specific scenario. But I have to show circle on other screens too but in different places, so if I follow this approach I will have to create circle for each screen. Is there any generic way in which I can just show half circle on any specific area of screen?

Comment: It's not possible with a `drawable` file to draw part of it, so you have to change it according to your needs .. glad that was helpful .. thanks to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can just take different images with that quarter circle placed in different places as per your requirement and set the image as a background of your layout.

You can use `ConstraintLayout` or `FrameLayout` as your parent layout. Here's an example with `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```